# Laravel 5.3 url() function alway print http://localhost

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have just switch to new version of laravel i.e. 5.3 for my new project.

Once I need to send registration mail to my portal customer, where registration mail contains account activation link where this mail is sent using Mail::queue.

I am generating that link using `url("activate/$random_string");`
and which always prints `http://localhost/activate/$random_string_value`

but what i wants is,

`http://localhost/project/public/activate/$random_string_value`

or

```
http://192.168.0.45/laravel/public/activate/$random_string_value
```

(above result i am getting till laravel 5.2)

i have set `APP_URL` value in `.env` as well and in `config/app.php` as well,

I have tried `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`

Can anybody help me to sort out this issue. I have one possible solution is to use `env('APP_URL')` to genrate same url.

Comment: Hello..are you implementing Email verification with Laravel?

Comment: Yes @Hiren Gohel Using laravel queue

Comment: Ok..first set url in `app/config/app.php`  then include config in your model like `use Config;` and then try `echo Config::get('app.url');`. See what result print? Is it give you as you say above?

Comment: I needs in mail.blade.php, and btw i had trid to print raw url using url('/')

Comment: Ok...I will implemented Email verification from this tutorial [ http://bensmith.io/email-verification-with-laravel ]. You may try it. It's easy and good to use and sorry i have not more idea about this:)

Comment: Are you setting up like this in `/config/app.php` file? `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),`

Comment: Yes have set the same but not getting effect

Comment: Try to set what you need. I mean to say like: `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/project/public'),`. I am not sure may be it works!!

Comment: why do you need the laravel/public part in your url? It's not supposed to be there.

Comment: @WouterVanDamme No issue if my index.php is outside public or i can create VirtualHost upto public directory

Answer (score -2):

I think your url need to update like:

```
url("activate/".$random_string);
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: This is same as `url("activate/$random_string");`

Comment: You might wanna remove this answer since it doesn't add any value.